# Missing classes in WMI when non-admin

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I'd like to be able to see `Win32_PhysicalMedia` information when logged in as
a *Limited User* in Windows XP (no admin rights). It works ok when logged in as *Admin*,
`WMIDiag` has just given a clean bill of health, and `Win32_DiskDrive` class
produces information correctly, but `Win32_PhysicalMedia` produces a count of 0
for this code

```
set WMI = GetObject("WinMgtmts:/root/cimv2")
set objs = WMI.InstancesOf("Win32_PhysicalMedia")
wscript.echo objs.count
```

Alternatively, if the hard disk serial number as found on the `SerialNumber`
property of the physical drives is available in another class which I can
read as a limited user please let me know. I am not attempting to write to
any property with WMI, but I can't read this when running as a *Limited User*.
Interestingly, `DiskDrive` misses out the `Signature` property, which would do for
my application when run as a *Limited User* but is present when run from an
*Admin* account.

Answer (score 1):

WMI does not give limited users this information.

If you can access Win32 functions from your language, you can call [GetVolumeInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364993(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: GetVolumeInformation does not provide physical media information